# Make non-nullable type in Java

Tags: java, null, nullable

Is it possible to make non-nullable type in Java? Objects of this type shouldn't can be null. How?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: very much possible now a days with Annotations

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is a reasonably common practice to use an @NotNull annotation which is supported by some IDEs and maven plugins.  In Java 8 you can write

```
@NotNull String text;
@NotNull List<@NotNull String> strings = ...;
```

This is not a language feature, but if you need this, it is available.

Note: there isn't a standard @NotNull annotation :(  So the tools which support this allow you to configure which one(s) you want.  I use the one which comes with IntelliJ.  It gives you warnings in the editor with auto-fixes and add runtime checks for `null` arguments, return values and variables.

Note: IntelliJ is able to work out if a field is not nullable by usage as well.

Comment: maybe, you should add some information of what is the result of doing this.

Comment: @Bathsheba , is it? Author did not mentioned, why one may want to add this notation. It won't, of course, save you from passing null into method, also there's no Compile-Time/Runtime validation. I think, answer should contain explanation, that this annotation is made for some code inspection.

Comment: @ginz There is validation as you write the code in the editor, and code injection for runtime validation.  You are right that there isn't compile time validation.

Answer (score 7):

I have recently come across the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) which has a [checker for null](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-annotations).

> @Nullable
>     indicates a type that includes the null value. For example, the type Boolean is nullable: a variable of type Boolean always has one of the values TRUE, FALSE, or null.
>
> @NonNull
>     indicates a type that does not include the null value. The type boolean is non-null; a variable of type boolean always has one of the values true or false. The type @NonNull Boolean is also non-null: a variable of type @NonNull Boolean always has one of the values TRUE or FALSE — never null. Dereferencing an expression of non-null type can never cause a null pointer exception.
>
> @PolyNull
>     indicates qualifier polymorphism. For a description of @PolyNull, see Section 19.2.
>
> @MonotonicNonNull
>      indicates a reference that may be null, but if it ever becomes non-null, then it never becomes null again. This is appropriate for lazily-initialized fields, among other uses. When the variable is read, its type is treated as @Nullable, but when the variable is assigned, its type is treated as @NonNull.

I have not had time yet to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. It is a language feature. At most what you can do is put null checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in pure Java. A `null` in Java is a literal value of a reference to a particular object.

Since all objects in Java are reference types, not allowing a `null` does not make grammatical sense.

Comment: Does make grammatically sense, the restriction does not alter the grammar of Core Java. If I want to stick with null object pattern this is a viable design decision, in fact ask Tony Hoare about his "milllion dollar mistake"

Comment: The same is true of C# - a reference type can be `null`. Except C# solved this by letting you just declare that reference types should never be `null`. And then like every good type system, the compiler checks it for you - and the runtime doesn't have to care about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in pure java, but the annotation `@nonnull` will tell the compiler to test for possible paths in which the object is assigned a null value. It then throws a build error requiring you to fix the object having a null value.